# TYPO3 9LTS - Images won't render after moving instance to a linux rootserver with plesk onyx

Tags: permissions, typo3, plesk, typo3-9.x

I recently moved a typo3 9lts instance from a managed server to a rootserver with linux plesk onyx. It seems to work fine, except the image won't render although they are there. I get a 'HTTP/2 403 Forbidden 21ms' error So I assume its a permission issue. If I look at an image e.g.

```
/fileadmin/_processed_/2/9/csm_typo3-book-backend-login_af97155c7b.png
```

... and compare the path, I have the following permission set for the managed server (MS) and root server (rs):

```
fileadmin
MS: rwx rwx r-x
RS: rwx r-x r-x 

_processed_
MS: rwx r-x ---
RS: rwx r-x --- 

2
MS: rwx rwx r-x
RS: rwx r-x r-x 

9
MS: rwx rwx r-x
RS: rwx r-x r-x 

csm_typo3-book-backend-login_af97155c7b.png
MS: rw- rw- r--
RS: rw- r-- r--
```

What do I need to do to render the images again? And if I need to change the permission what's the best way to I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Re-render images

You can use the InstallTool (Maintenance › Remove Temporary Assets) to re-render images.

## Permissions

You should think about a permission concept that fits your use case.

I'll just suggest how I do it - there are many other ways that are equally possible.

## Find out which usergroup your webserver uses

```
# search for php-fpm (or apache, or nginx, ... depending on which process runs PHP when accessed via the web on your server)
sudo ps -o command,user,group -p $(pgrep php-fpm)
```

## Put the user that is changing files into the same group

That might be the user(s) that you use for deployment to the server, the user an FTP-daemon runs on, ...

```
sudo usermod -a -G WEBSERVER_GROUP YOUR_USERNAME
```

## Set user/group/permissions on the web app directory

```
cd YOUR_APP_ROOT_DIR # e.g. /var/www/my_typo3
sudo chown -R WEBSERVER_USER:WEBSERVER_GROUP .
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
```

This also sets the setgid-bit on directories which means that newly created subdirectories will have the same group.

## Make sure new files do also get created with these permissions

Check that new files created by your user (or FTP daemon, or ...) will give full permissions to the group!

```
umask
# that should start with 000 - e.g. 0002 is OK, 0007 would be most secure
```

If it is wrong (commonly found: 0022), set it with `umask 0002`. The easiest to persist is usually to set it in /etc/profile or ~/.bashrc.

Also make sure TYPO3 gives full write permissions to the group and sets the setgid:

```
# In LocalConfiguration.php: (or wherever you set your TYPO3 configuration):
SYS/fileCreateMask = '0660' # you can ignore the last digit, 0 for maximum security
SYS/folderCreateMask = '2770' # you can ignore the last digit
```

## Checks

Log out and back in again.

```
umask # should be 000x
groups # should include the webserver group

# create files and folders with your user 
# create files and folders in TYPO3 "File List" module and check permissions
```

---

This should be a safe setup that is very resilient against running into permission problems. It allows direct upload from an IDE. It allows files to be changed by multiple users/daemons.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. On the first try when running: sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {}\; & sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 2770 {}\; I got an error though: Error: find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: ... a space was missing like: sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; & sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;

Comment: Yet, TYPO3 wouldn't render the files ... still no permissions, so I did: sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \; & sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \; ... now its working

Comment: And will the 0664 and 2775 be a problem?

Comment: right, the space was missing. Thanks, I will edit thie answer.
0664/2775 will not be a problem. It gives read access to everybody with an account on the server but usually that's fine.

Comment: But if it is not working otherwise that means that your webserver group differs from the file's group. You could check which group and permissions new files and directories get when you add them via the TYPO3 backend -> File List.

Answer (score 0):

First you should try clear TYPO3 maintenance > flush cache , remove temp file , process file, give required permissions , check other issues and then Try to fix with permission , some time major problems solved by backend flush cache ..