# TYPO3 v10LTS - Error - Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1573385431: RSS URL could not be fetched | RuntimeException

Tags: php, ubuntu, typo3, plesk, typo3-10.x

I have a new TYPO3 v10LTS (v4.4) installed on a root server with Ubuntu 16LTS and Plesk.

When I login to the BE and go to the 'Dashboard', the widget news shows this red message:

```
An error occurred while retrieving information for this widget. Please try again, and if the problem persists, contact your administrator.
```

I also get a log error:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1573385431: RSS URL could not be fetched | RuntimeException thrown in file /var/www/httpdocs/typo3_src-10.4.4/typo3/sysext/dashboard/Classes/Widgets/RssWidget.php in line 106. Requested URL: project-url/typo3/index.php?route=%%2Fajax%%2Fdashboard%%2Fwidget%%2Fcontent&token=--AnonymizedToken--&widget=t3news
```

When I then go for instance on the page module it takes quite some time for it to load and page tree items are missing. Sometimes the server breaks down and the frontend is not accessible and shows an error. The error_log file shows this error:

```
[Sun Oct 24 20:00:06.87213 2021] [evasive20:error] [pid 13801] [client ip:53534] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/httpdocs/project/typo3/index.php, referer: project-url/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmain&token=d5da26e3df928sdffa36e0df6597c71
```

I had some previous permissioning issue I think I have solved:

- [TYPO3 9LTS - Images won't render after moving instance to a linux rootserver with plesk onyx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62220971/typo3-9lts-images-wont-render-after-moving-instance-to-a-linux-rootserver-wit)
- [Plesk - TYPO3 10LTS - Client denied by server configuration error when trying to access page module & fail2ban locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265273/plesk-typo3-10lts-client-denied-by-server-configuration-error-when-trying-to)

I've set the following rights for folder /project and recursive:

```
Permission:     User:       Group:
rwx rwx r-x     www-data    psacln
```

And I ran:

```
$ sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
$ sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;


$ user:/var/www/httpdocs/project$ ls -la
drwxrwsr-x  6 www-data  psacln   4096 Jun  8  2020 fileadmin
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data  psacln  13793 Okt 21 19:54 .htaccess
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data  psacln     19 Jun  8  2020 index.php -> typo3_src/index.php
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data  psacln     15 Jun  8  2020 typo3 -> typo3_src/typo3
drwxrwsr-x  6 www-data  psacln   4096 Okt 21 19:06 typo3conf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 www-data  psacln     19 Jun  9  2020 typo3_src -> ../typo3_src-10.4.4
drwxrwsr-x  4 www-data  psacln   4096 Jun  8  2020 typo3temp

$ user:/var/www/httpdocs$ ls -la
drwxrwsr-x  4 www-data  psacln  4096 Jun  9  2020 typo3_src-10.4.4

$ user:/var/www/httpdocs/typo3_src-10.4.4$ ls -la
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data  psacln   11508 Jun  9  2020 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data  psacln  300325 Jun  9  2020 composer.lock
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data  psacln    1013 Jun  9  2020 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data  psacln     947 Jun  9  2020 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data  psacln    1418 Jun  9  2020 INSTALL.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data  psacln   18425 Jun  9  2020 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data  psacln    6730 Jun  9  2020 README.md
drwxrwsr-x  3 www-data  psacln    4096 Jun  9  2020 typo3
drwxrwsr-x 15 www-data  psacln    4096 Jun  9  2020 vendor
```

Some further information:

The PHP version is 7.3.27 and I set the php execution on FPM from Apache. php-info shows 'FPM/FastCGI'

```
$ user:/var/www/httpdocs$ sudo ps -o command,user,group -p $(pgrep php-fpm)
COMMAND                     USER     GROUP
php-fpm: master process (/o root     root
php-fpm: master process (/e root     root
php-fpm: pool www           www-data www-data
php-fpm: pool www           www-data www-data

$ user:/var/www/httpdocs$ sudo ps -o command,user,group -p $(pgrep nginx)
COMMAND                     USER     GROUP
nginx: master process /usr/ root     root
nginx: worker process       nginx    nginx

$ user:/var/www/httpdocs$ sudo ps -o command,user,group -p $(pgrep apache)
COMMAND                     USER     GROUP
/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start  root     root
/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start  www-data www-data

$ user:/var/www/httpdocs$ getent group psacln
psacln:x:1003:www-data
```

How can I solve this issue?

Edit: Checking for curl shows:

```
$ user:/var/www/httpdocs$ curl -I https://www.typo3.org/rss
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

phpinfo() shows

```
cURL Information 7.47.0
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your exception code the error occurs during fetching https://www.typo3.org/rss for the news widget in the dashboard extension.
That's not related to your permission problems.

I think there are three possible reasons:

1. https://www.typo3.org/rss could have been temporarily unavailable. But at least at the moment, the RSS feed works fine.
2. Your web server / PHP doesn't have cURL installed. You can check that on the CLI of your server with `curl -I https://www.typo3.org/rss` which should result in `HTTP/2 302`.
3. There is a firewall on your server which blocks outgoing requests.

Comment: Checking for curl shows the above edit. It looks like its available but it says ssl verification failed. Might this be the cause?

Comment: Maybe its this issue: https://askubuntu.com/a/1368591 . I'll try tomorrow

Comment: According to your edit, SSL is the problem, not the firewall. I'm not pro regarding server administration but Ubuntu 16 seems to be slightly outdated. Maybe openssl is the problem. At least the error message shows clearly that your machine can't verify the SSL certificate of typo3.org. Maybe that due to the recent expiration of the Let's Encrypt root certificate. But than needs to be fixed on your side.